# Putting this command into bash script

Tags: bash, scripting

with help of google , script that measures multicast streams bandwidth.

Here it is
 `tcpdump -tnn -i eth1 -f multicast | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $3,"> "$5,$1*$NF/2*8/1024 " Kbps"}' | awk '$1 > 10' & sleep 2s && pkill -HUP -f tcpdump`

It turns out fine, except I need to hit enter to get back to prompt.
 I know it is && problem, but dont know how to fix it.

How can I trascribe it to shell script. And maybe add $var for number of seconds.

Comment: You have to press enter? If I put that in a script and run it, I have to press CTRL C to exit which returns me straight to the prompt. You need to explain your situation better.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `timeout` to kill the tcpdump after a duration:

```
(timeout -s HUP 2 tcpdump -tnn -i eth1 -f multicast || true) | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $3,"> "$5,$1*$NF/2*8/1024 " Kbps"}' | awk '$1 > 10'
```

To script it:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! [[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
        echo "Usage: $0 <number of seconds>"
        exit 1
fi

(timeout -s HUP $1 tcpdump -tnn -i eth1 -f multicast || true) | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $3,"> "$5,$1*$NF/2*8/1024 " Kbps"}' | awk '$1 > 10'
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to press enter to exit. it's just a cosmetical issue here. that is because your output "overwrites" your terminal (you can still enter any command and press enter - it will be executed).

To "fix" this layout issue you can try to append "; sleep 1; echo" to your line so it will look like:

```
tcpdump -tnn -i eth1 -f multicast | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $3,"> "$5,$1*$NF/2*8/1024 " Kbps"}' | awk '$1 > 10' & sleep 2s && pkill -HUP -f tcpdump; sleep 1; echo
```

Hope that helps.

And here is your bash script with variable:

```
#!/bin/bash

SLEEPTIME=5

tcpdump -tnn -i eth0 -f multicast | sort | uniq -c | awk -v a=$SLEEPTIME '{print $3,"> "$5,$1*$NF/a*8/1024 " Kbps"}' | awk '$1 > 10' & sleep $SLEEPTIME && pkill -HUP -f tcpdump; sleep 1; echo
```